# Changed Bios Boot Settings - Now Windows won't Boot

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, bios

I've got a 500GB Samsung NVME drive running Win 10 Pro that is throwing this error when trying to boot:

```
Your PC needs to be repaired. The application or operating system couldn’t be loaded
because a required file is missing or contains errors. File: 

\windows\system32\winload.efi Error code: 0xc000***
```

I believe the problem is that I was messing around with my BIOS Boot Options. Long story short I got a new 2TB NMVE drive that I was troubleshooting getting to boot a fresh install of Windows 10 Pro.  Eventually I got the new drive to work but now my old one doesn't.

To be clear the old 500GB drive was disconnected while I was installing the new windows os to the new 2TB drive. I can still access all the contents of the old drive if I use it as an external drive. It just doesn't boot.

**I'm almost certain this is from me fiddling with the Bios Boot Settings.**

Things I changed:

- Cleared the Secure Boot Keys
- Messed around with the Secure Boot Setting (changed it from "other os" to "Windows UEFI Boot" and back)

Running Windows 10 Pro on a ASUS ROG Strix Z390-E Motherboard with Intel Core i9-10900K CPU

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to enable CSM  in the BIOS.

Comment: Try resetting BIOS to default values.

Comment: You could try unplugging the new drive, and then boot the PC from a windows installation medium, and choose repair installation. When there are no errors found, you may need to create a recovery stick first, and try again with that one. Maybe after your old installation is repaired, it will boot while the other drive is not plugged in, and then maybe it works also if both drives are plugged in